django Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'carray[0]'
I received the mistake below with this situation.
Code:
def check_url_exists(url_to_check):
    try:
        countArray= []
        # محاولة استرداد سجل بناءً على الرابط المعطى
        display_obj = Display.objects.get(url=url_to_check)
        for i in range(1, 6):
        # حساب عدد السجلات where choosenum = i
         count = Display_Data.objects.filter(url=url_to_check, choosenum=i).count()
         print(count)# إضافة عدد السجلات إلى القائمة
         countArray.append(count)
        return countArray  # الرابط موجود في قاعدة البيانات
    except Display.DoesNotExist:
        countArray= [0,0,0,0,0]
        return countArray
def display_video(request, url):
    # تشكيل الـ URL الكامل لإطار الفيديو على YouTube
    embed_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{url}"
    full_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={url}"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(full_url).content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.title.text
    # استخدم نموذج "display_data"
    countArry=check_url_exists(url)
# استخدم "Count" لحساب عدد السجلات
        

# طباعة النتيجة

       
                 

        # مرر الـ embed_url وعنوان الفيديو إلى القالب
    return render(request, 'display/videoA.html', {'embed_url': embed_url , 'title': title,'carry':countArry})  
and templet have include sentence 
    <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">>
        <!-- زر "نجحت" -->
        <button type="submit" name="CHOOSE"  value="1" class="btn btn-success mr-2">{{carray[0]}} نجحت</button>
        <!-- زر "فشلت" -->
        <button type="submit" name="CHOOSE" value="2" btn btn-danger mr-2">{{carray[1]}}فشلت</button>
        <!-- زر "تحتاج إلى مال" --> 
        <button type="submit" name="CHOOSE" value="3" class="btn btn-warning mr-2">تحتاج إلى مال{{carray[2]}}</button>
        <!-- زر "تحتاج إلى أدوات" -->
        <button type="submit" name="CHOOSE" value="4" btn btn-info mr-2">{{carray[3]}}تحتاج إلى أدوات</button>
        <!-- زر "مؤجل" -->
        <button type="submit" name="CHOOSE" value="5" class="btn btn-secondary">{{carray[4]}}مؤجل</button>
            <!-- زر "اخر نجاح" -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-2">اخر نجاح</button>
            <!-- زر "اخر فشل" -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-2">اخر فشل</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>


I have a Django project. I try to display a video from YouTube, and the user can evaluate it. I saved the evaluation in a database I want to show data for every video that I show.

You can not subscript in a template so {{ x[y] }} is not allowed.

what can i make insted

As stated above by sir @willeM_Van onsem in the above comment:

You can not subscript in a template so {{ x[y] }} is not allowed.

Now you can pass the countArry as a list of values instead of trying to access it with subscripts in the template. For example, you can pass it as:
return render(request, 'display/videoA.html', {'embed_url': embed_url , 'title': title,'carry_0': countArry[0], 'carry_1': countArry[1], 'carry_2': countArry[2], 'carry_3': countArry[3], 'carry_4': countArry[4]})

Then, in your template, you can access these variables directly like {{ carry_0 }}, {{ carry_1 }}, and so on.

thank you for your time it done but the code not count as i expected
